# javafx module javafx.scene.media.AudioClip not found

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

I'm working on some school projects for a class on NetBeans with TMC. I'm at a point where I'm practicing the use of javafx. Javafx has worked without a hitch until now. I'm trying to "import javafx.scene.media.AudioClips;" and it says the package "javafx.scene.media" does not exist.
If I try to build the project I get these error messages:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Osa14_08.Hurraa: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call(MultiThreadedBuilder.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 11 more
```

I have tried to find solutions for this (adding things to pom, download javafx and add it to the JDK), but none have worked. I'm thinking the problem in finding and executing any solution is my level of understanding how these things work.

Comment: `javafx.scene.media` is in the `javafx.media` module. Did you try adding that?

Comment: I guess I have not. By adding, do you mean importing it to the project or adding it to the JDK as if it's missing from my javafx?
Specific instructions or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: From the [javafx website](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), you should be able to add new modules by going to `Properties -> Run` and add the VM options `--module-path <javafx lib path> --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media`, where "javafx lib path" is the path to your javafx sdk lib folder.

Comment: Downloaded javafx-sdk-11.0.2 from the website, unzipped it and put the contents into a folder.
Went to Properties -> Run, on Configuration: <default config> it says on the bottom of the window: "One of Run/Debug/Profile Project actions has been modified and the Run panel cannot be safely edited"
Changing configuration to "java11 (Profile)" allows me to modify the VM Options and to add the commands given, but i haven't seen any improvement in finding the .AudioClips module.

Comment: This is getting a little out of my realm of expertise, but given you're using Maven to build, what do you have in the `<dependencies>` tag in pom?

Answer (score 5):

I am taking the Helsinki Java MOOC course too and ran into the same problem.

In your pom.xml file find the dependency that looks like this,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

then add a new dependency under it .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure the version number is the same as the javafx-controls dependency version.